# Grid pattern. Help me to solve the puzzle

Tags: pattern

What is the missing grid like? I just cannot recognize any rule.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this would make sense.

> [image]

So

> The middle is mirrored along the diagonal and the outer are moved diagonally downright. Of course, there are many variations to this. It could be the upper that is always is moved downright diagonally and the lower that is mirrored along the diagonal, but that would produce an overlap.

Comment: I think the second alternative solution is better. There are two separate groups of 3 grids in each. The spatial relationship maybe includes the information what the left sided grids must do  other words the middle one should do the two different transformation because it is logically connnected with both others on the right column..but i am not sure either. Otherwise both of  your ideas seem to be logical

Comment: This is the problem with this kind of puzzles...

Comment: Yes but maybe the second makes more sense. If you see the five as a whole than symmetry (the middle one has one function towards both right sided grids) would make sense but the 5 grids as a whole does noy exist as a consistent pattern. So it is contradictory. Secondly if you see the right side functions as a sequence,from up to down translation, flipping, who knows what the function of the bottom one will be...it is already logical speculation but more things says that the overlap is the better one compaired with the reasons that prioritizes  the first solution

Comment: Or we are on wrong track.. this is possible if there are two solutions and it is such hard to make a difference. These puzzles usually have a unique one where you are not in doubt, and this means the solution is purely not yet found.